# How to display a picture on homepage that is uploaded through registration?

Tags: python, django

I am having a problem with displaying a profile picture for every user after the user is done with the registration. I can see the pictures are being saved after the upload to the `/media/profile_pictures` folder, but I can't find a way to display that picture on the homepage.

Please look at the code samples. I was following the Tango with Django tutorial for uploading a picture, but none of the questions that I found here and are related to this problem did not really help me.

`forms.py`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
       model = UserProfile
       fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

`views.py`:

```
def register(request):
  context = RequestContext(request)
  registered = False

  if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        if 'picture' in request.FILES:
            profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

        profile.save()

        registered = True

    else:
        print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request,'webapp/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered})
```

`models.py`:

```
      class UserProfile(models.Model):
         user = models.OneToOneField(User)
         website = models.URLField(blank=True)
         picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

         def __unicode__(self):
           return self.user.username
```

settings.py

```
     MEDIA_URL = '/media/profile_images/'
     MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

`home.html`:

```
  <img src="{{ user.UserProfile.picture.url }}" width="240">
```

And in the `urls.py` I have added

```
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I have fixed it. Sorry, I'm quite new at this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lowercase `UserProfile` I think it will work:

```
<img src="{{ user.userprofile.picture.url }}" width="240">
```

The [documentation for `OneToOneField` says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

> If you do not specify the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument for the `OneToOneField`, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.